# Does Islam support putting flowers on a grave to reduce punishment?

Tags: sunnah, islamic-basis, death

On a recent visit to a Muslim graveyard, I see people put rose petals on the graves of their loved ones.

On inquiry, I was informed that the Prophet (SAW) once put a leaf on the grave to reduce the punishment of that grave's occupant.

So my queries are:

1. Does putting leaves/flowers reduce one's punishment?
2. Can leaves as used by the Prophet be substituted by flowers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hadith is in Sahih Muslim:

> Once the Prophet, while passing through one of the graveyards of
> Medina or Mecca heard the voices of two persons who were being
> tortured in their graves. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "These two persons are
> being tortured not for a major sin (to avoid)." The Prophet (ﷺ) then
> added, "Yes! (they are being tortured for a major sin). Indeed, one of
> them never saved himself from being soiled with his urine while the
> other used to go about with calumnies (to make enmity between
> friends). The Prophet (ﷺ) then asked for a green leaf of a date-palm
> tree, broke it into two pieces and put one on each grave. On being
> asked why he had done so, he replied, "I hope that their torture might
> be lessened, till these get dried." ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/82))

From this hadith, some scholars say that putting flowers on graves is allowed.

I can't translate this fatwa, but if know Arabic, see this: [IslamWeb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/24505).  And some of those who said it's allowed, say that giving the price of those flowers as sadaqa on behalf of the dead is better.

Some others say it's not allowed because in another long hadith in sahih muslim the prophet (peace be upon him) mentioned that the reduction of punishment happened because of his shafaa (intercession):

> he said (the prophet peace be upon him): I passed by two graves the occupants of which had been
> undergoing torment. I liked to make intercession for them so that the
> might be relieved of this torment y as long as these twigs remain
> fresh

In Arabic:

> قَالَ ‏"‏ إِنِّي مَرَرْتُ بِقَبْرَيْنِ يُعَذَّبَانِ فَأَحْبَبْتُ
> بِشَفَاعَتِي أَنْ يُرَفَّهَ عَنْهُمَا مَا دَامَ الْغُصْنَانِ
> رَطْبَيْنِ ‏"‏

From this hadith, some scholars says that this act is private to the prophet (peace be upon him).  So there is difference of opinions on this issue.

Comment: Jazakallah Khair for the answer. So if I understand correctly,  there is no scholarly consensus on this topic. Correct?

Comment: yes !  that's what i read :)

Comment: there is more information in the link but it's in arabic :/

Comment: you don't know arabic ?

Comment: Jazakallah khair. I will go through the link. Yes, I understand Arabic :)

Comment: allah bless you !
you can ask here if you want 
https://islamqa.info/en/

Comment: or here http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=fatwa&tab=3

Comment: hey can you translate what you understand  from this 
http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36171/need-a-translation

Comment: @Ahmed i want to add something 
if putting flowers become like the christian way every one put expensive roses  everytime he come and such thing 
then it's another problem called " التشبه بالكفار " 
so to be honest in my country a lot of people  planed some plants on graves but this look normal and scholars don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

I think if the answers are not clear and it raises concerns its best to leave a grave as it is .. I lost my father 6 weeks ago and having read so many things about planting and leaving flowers on the grave there is no clear answer so why add things to a grave rather leave it plain simple and keep it clean yes grass etc may grow over time im told old dead grass can be removed that's it I think I have answerd my own question now on if I should put a plant on the grave I think il say no and leave it plain and simple

Jzk khairan

Comment: I am sorry to hear about your father. May Allah bless him with a high rank in Jannatul Firdaus and grant your family sabr in these hard times.

Answer (score -2):

Surely by copying of profit Cannot be detrimental to one’s life as with regards to the “Mayats” in the graves I agree that the  money spent on flowers could possibly be more beneficial if given towards a good cause eg: to orphanage.

Comment: I think you should focus more on improving your spelling before commenting here. Phrases like "copying of profit" is disrespectful. Edit your answer or delete your answer right now.