# Is decorating the grave with flowers allowed it bid’at

Tags: halal-haram, bidah, grave

My grandfather has recently passed and I heard from a relative that they are planting flowers for him by his grave.

I have read in a kitaab that it’s considered bidah . And I want to tell them to remove the flowers but I need proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Islam support putting flowers on a grave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36161/does-islam-support-putting-flowers-on-a-grave)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Those acts are considered **Bid'ah** which are done as an "Islamic" deed but Islam never prescribed them.

So, in this matter, actually, they have to prove if Allah said to plant flowers by the grave or the Rasool Sallallahu 'Alaihi Wa Sallam, or the Sahaba ever planted flowers on graves.

Alhamdulillah, Nobody can ever prove that Allah said so or Rasool or his Sahaba ever did anything close to that. So it cannot be an Islamic act or a good deed. Thus if they do it for the sake of Allah or as an Islamic Act, it will be a Bid'ah.

Rather Rasool Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam always forbade exaggerating about the death and deads.

There is a hadith narrated by Muslim in his Sahih that, Jabir said:

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade that the graves should be plastered or they are used as sitting places (for the people), or a building should be built over them. [Sahih Muslim; No: 970]

So, it will be Bid'ah and Haram to plant flowers by the grave and it can also be a medium of Shirk afterward.

Comment: It won't necessarily lead to shirk. Still it is a bid'ah